Issues using IDesignTimeDbContextFactory: Cannot connect to database and ambiguos constructors
I have 3 projects in my solution: Web API, ClassLibrary and MVC. I have a shared DbContext which is located in ClassLibrary. I tried adding a migration in ClassLibrary and that failed because it is not an executable project. Searching online I found that in cases like this you must use a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory and so I implemented one.
using ClassLibrary.Models.Database;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserPortfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PortfolioGameBox> GameBoxes { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration) : base()
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");

            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }
    }

    public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var connectionString = args[0];

            Console.WriteLine($"Using connection string: {connectionString}");

            builder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));

            return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}

But when I run Add-Migration Portfolios -Args "<connectionString>" in the Package Manager Console with the project set to ClassLibrary, I get an "Access denied" error. It's worth noting that the connection string is valid, in fact it works when not using IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.
Moreover when I run the MVC project I get a Some services are not able to be constructed error:
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext': Unable to activate type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext])) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ClassLibrary.Services.IUserManager Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ClassLibrary.Services.UserManager': Unable to activate type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext])) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ClassLibrary.Services.IProfileManager Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: ClassLibrary.Services.ProfileManager': Unable to activate type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext]))
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\Development\Project\API\Program.cs:line 65

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext': Unable to activate type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext])

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to activate type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext])

The services mentioned in the stack trace both use ApplicationDbContext through DI and when I remove the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory the errors stop appearing.
